# Theme change on rotate

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-theme

I'm having many issues with themes in my app, when rotating the screen, to landscape, the theme is changed and back to "default", I'm using AppCompat's DayNight mode, when rotated the screen, mode back to "day".
I have already tried several things, but save all the content of the app, and recreate the activity in onResume setting the new theme (night) becomes very heavy, having a delay of 2 to 3 seconds, which completely breaks the user's experience when returning to the recyclerView.

*Manifest*

```
 <activity
        android:name=".videoPlayer.PlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="Player"
         />
```

*my Theme*

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/backgroundColor</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>
```

*set DayNight theme on MainActivity*

```
     getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(
                    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            recreate();
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, I just added:

```
 getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(
                    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

In a class extending Application.